# How to customise the icon of an areablock in Pimcore

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

The company I work for uses **Pimcore 6** to make websites.
In the adminpanel while editing a page you can add `areablocks` to your content.
When you click on the plus sign, you can add a new `areablock`, I have noticed that the `areablocks` have a random icon next to their name.
I thought that this was because the person who created them was too lazy to create or add the right ones.

[image]

After looking at the official [DEMO](https://demo.pimcore.fun/admin/?perspective=CMS) on the **Pimcore** website. I noticed that their `areablocks` also have random icons.

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to customise these?

After doing some [research](https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Documents/Editables/Areablock/Bricks.html) it seems that this is possible by adding a `icon.png` into your areablock's folder.

[image]

That's what I have tried. But the random icon is still displaying. My custom icon is getting ignored.
Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Good question I would also like to know. Really have no idea why they downvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting the icon into the view is not helpful (or was some wrong information). When you are registering a brick and check the methods of `AbstractTemplateAreabrick` you will notice that it has some class `getIcon()`. And this is the method you have to override in case you want to set custom icons.

The `AreabrickInterface` defines the method like this:

```
/**
 * Icon as absolute path, e.g. /bundles/websitedemo/img/areas/foo/icon.png
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getIcon();
```

An absolute image URL is needed. In my case I just do it with base64 .svgs - here is a working example:

```
class Accordion extends AbstractAreabrick
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->translator->trans('Accordion');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->translator->trans('for collapsed contents');
    }

    public function getIcon() {
        return "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to trigger the icon used next to all areablock which is a step into the right direction. But now all areablocks have the same image.

Comment: Nevermind I did implement the code in the wrong file. Thanks man!

Comment: any idea about the relative path to use my custom `icon.png`?

Comment: while `return './../bundles/pimcoreadmin/img/flat-color-icons/biomass.svg';`works, my custom path: `return './../Resources/views/Areas/accordion/icon.png';` is not working

Comment: According to the docs you should pass an absolute path (the path is directly rendered). I guess your views folder is not accessible like this in the backend. Just put your images into some publicly accessible location and pass an absolute path.